# Calculator for more than two numbers

Tags: c#, console, calculator

I am having this problem with my code.  I have variables `firstnumber` and `secondnumber`, as well as `operand` and `result`. Then I am using the `string.Split` to know whether it's an operator or a number.

After that I have used a `while` loop if `a.Length` is over 2 and if it is, I declared an `double numbers` which is `a[i]`. `i` is `3` and gets `+ 2` every time the while loop executes.

Then I declared a variable called operands which is `a[b]`.  `b = 4` and gets `+ 2` every time the loop executes. Then I want to compare the string operands and the string operator, to see if it is `+`, `-`, `*` or `/` in the end I have put an `if` statement, so that `if a[i] == null`, then the `while` loop breaks and the `result` is printed.

I know my code is messy, and I have probably done many things wrong here, so I would really appreciate every word of advice I can get.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
 class Calculator
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a calculator. enter the numbers this way: Example(4 + 3)");
        Console.WriteLine("!Use space between numbers!");
        start : string s = Console.ReadLine(); 
        overagain:  string [] avgränsare = { " " };
        string[] a = s.Split(avgränsare, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

        while (a.Length > 2)
        {
            int i = 3;
            int b = 4;
            double numbers = double.Parse(a[i]);
            i = i + 2;
            b = b + 2;

            double firstnumber = double.Parse(a[0]);
            string operand = a[1];
            double secondnumber = double.Parse(a[2]);
            double result = 0;
            string operands = a[b];
            goto overagain;

                if (a[i] == null)
                {
                  Console.WriteLine(result);
                  break;
                }
            }

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
        s = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        if (s == "y")
        {
            goto start;
        }
        else
        {
        }

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have written an answer that should help you clean up your code. Unfortunately, you shouldn't expect any answers to extend the functionality of your code. Code Review is for cleaning up existing code. Code Review is not for adding features to, or modify the results of, existing code.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/

Answer (score 9):

## Using `goto` is not a good practice!!

Instead of using `goto`, use a do-while or a `while` loop. You want to do something as long as the answer to "Do you want to continue" is "Yes". This is perfect for a do-while loop.

You should also avoid using `goto overagain` and instead use a for-loop to iterate through the array. It could also be solved with recursion. Use anything you want **except the `goto` statement!**

---

Make your code self-documenting. Your "explanation" of your code in the beginning of your question confuses me more than helps me.

Self-document your code by using **proper variable names**. `s` can be called `input` instead, and i and b can be called something that explains what they are doing. Right now, I can't exactly understand what they are supposed to do.

---

Your last block of `Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");`, including the if-else that comes afterwards should be indented one step further.

---

If you don't have anything to do in else, just skip that part. `if ... { ... }` is enough, you don't need else. You'd better remove this, *or else*...

---

Use English names for variables, especially when characters outside the range of A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _ are included (such as "ä"). The Swedish word "avgränsare" translates to "delimiter" in English.

Comment: Thanks. However i posted this in stackoverflow, and they Said i should go to this place.

Comment: @RickardB. That is most likely because your question is very unclear, **and** you are asking for a "cleanup" (which is on-topic here). Please show me the link of your StackOverflow question and I can see if there are any differences. Either way, if you would ask "how can I add this functionality to my code" on StackOverflow then they would likely tell you to try something first and then come back and ask a **specific** question.